# #assoc does not work on arrays initialized with %w, why?

Tags: ruby

Please explain why [s1] will return the expected behavior in this example from the documentation, but [s2] will not return similar results?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

s1 = [ "colors", "red", "blue", "green" ]
s2 = %w( letters, a, b, c )
s3 = "foo"

a = [ s1, s2, s3 ]

puts a.assoc "colors"
msg = a.assoc("colors").nil? ? "value is nil" : "value is true"
puts msg

puts a.assoc "letters"
msg = a.assoc("letters").nil? ? "value is nil" : "value is true"
puts msg
```

Produces:

```
colors
red
blue
green
value is true

value is nil
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`%w` notation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings) expects items to be separated by *plain spaces*:

```
# s2 = %w( letters, a, b, c ) # WRONG
  s2 = %w( letters a b c )    # CORRECT
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some unnecessary commas in your `s2` array variable

```
s2 = %w( letters, a, b, c )
```

So your `a` array of arrays variable looks like

```
[["colors", "red", "blue", "green"], ["letters,", "a,", "b,", "c"], "foo"]
```

So, `a.assoc "letters,"` should work

```
puts a.assoc "letters,"
msg = a.assoc("letters,").nil? ? "value is nil" : "value is true"
puts msg
```

Produces:

```
letters,
a,
b,
c
value is true
```

However, [mudasobwa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42712093/3519459) is correct

> [`%w` notation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings) expects items to be separated by *plain spaces*:
>
> ```
> # s2 = %w( letters, a, b, c ) # WRONG
>   s2 = %w( letters a b c )    # CORRECT
> ```

Comment: There is no need to copy-paste correct answer into yours. I have no plans to remove it.